# Redirect page with Prototype after a one minute

Tags: javascript, redirect, timeout, prototypejs

Dipping my toes into Prototype again and am unsure how to move forward with this simple function. I'd like to redirect the page to another after 1 minute.

I've seen `window.location.href = window.location.href;` for redirecting to itself, so it's easy enough to say `window.location.href = "/one";` but how do I include the time out of 60,000ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
      //do something
}, 60000); //do something in 60,000 ms
```